# firebase deploy error and fiebase.json empty file

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I'm following this tutorial [Getting Started with Firebase Hosting on the Web - Firecasts](https://youtu.be/meofoNuK3vo)

I'm trying to host a simple index.html file in firebase but when I type **firebase deploy** its gives me the following error:

No targets found. Valid targets are: database,storage,functions,hosting.  [hosting error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/csK7b.png)

I found my firebase.json file is empty it contains only **{ }** .

Comment: Thanks j0k for updating question.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

run `firebase init` again.

When you are asked for - Which Firebase CLI features do you want to setup for this folder?

**Press Space to select features**, it will mark that feature with **asterisk**.

Then Enter to confirm your choices.

Make sure you select the options by pressing spacebar, then press enter.

Comment: Thank you so much Amresh.
my mistake was that, i'm selecting that option by up & down key and then pressing enter.

Comment: I had exactly the same problem. I didn't know there was the option to use `space-bar` only up-down and enter!!! So confusing.

Answer (score 2):

run **firebase init** and if your **firebase.json** is empty with only **{}** then add

```
 {
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ]
  }
}
```

replace **"public": "app"** with **"public": "public"**

then run **firebase deploy**